# Laravel session flash message and buttons

Tags: php, session, button, laravel-5

sorry for the newbie question.

I want to create a href content for a button in the controller.
I can do

```
route('routename', ['parameters' => ''])
```

but how can I add a flash message to be passed in the new page when the button is fired and redirected successifully?

Like the classical:

```
redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

Comment: use the Session class

Comment: more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Session of Laravel make same you want.

You can refer here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

**Example:**

In controller file:

```
public function store(PostRequest $request) {
    if (Post::create($request->all())) {
        $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'success');
        $request->session()->flash('message.content', 'Post was successfully added!');
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'danger');
        $request->session()->flash('message.content', 'Error!');
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

In view file:

```
@if(session()->has('message.level'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message.level') }}"> 
    {!! session('message.content') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

Good luck!